# A full-duplex connection to an IRC server

Tags: c++, socket, boost, chat

This connection class can be used, through composition, to make IRC clients for different kinds of IRC services.

```
#ifndef CONNECTION_HPP
#define CONNECTION_HPP

#include <string>
#include <queue>
#include <functional>
#include <tuple>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

#include "irc_exception.hpp"
#include "messages/message.hpp"

namespace dapps
{
    namespace irc
    {
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        /// <summary>
        ///             Defines methods to manage a full-duplex connection to an irc server.
        ///             The connection asynchronously loops, checking for messages from the server,
        ///             and provides a user the ability to asynchronously write messages to such server.
        /// </summary>
        ///
        /// <remarks>   Falven, 2/26/2016. </remarks>
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        class connection
        {
        public:
            connection(boost::asio::io_service & io_service)
                : io_service_(io_service),
                resolver_(io_service),
                socket_(io_service),
                message_queue_(),
                reply_buffer_(),
                read_handler_(),
                resolved_(false),
                connected_(false)
            {   
            }

            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            /// <summary>   Resolves and establishes the connection to the provided endpoint. </summary>
            ///
            /// <remarks>   Falven, 3/1/2016. </remarks>
            ///
            /// <param name="host"> The host to establish the connecttion to. </param>
            /// <param name="port"> The port to establish the connecttion to. </param>
            /// <param name="handler">  A handler to invoke when the connection has been established. </param>
            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            void establish_async(const std::string & host,
                const std::string & port,
                const std::function<void(const boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator & iterator)> & handler = {})
            {
                resolver_.async_resolve({ host, port },
                    [this, handler](const boost::system::error_code & error, boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator iterator)
                {
                    switch (error.value())
                    {
                        case boost::system::errc::success:
                        {
                            resolved_ = true;
                            do_connect(iterator, handler);
                            break;
                        }
                        default:
                        {
                            do_error("Resolve attempt failed", error);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            /// <summary>   Closes the connection. </summary>
            ///
            /// <remarks>   Falven, 3/1/2016. </remarks>
            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            void close()
            {
                io_service_.post([this]() { socket_.close(); });
            }

            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            /// <summary>   Set a handler to execute when reading asynchronous messages from the server. </summary>
            ///
            /// <remarks>   Falven, 3/1/2016. </remarks>
            ///
            /// <param name="handler">  The handler to invoke when a message has been read. </param>
            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            void read_async(const std::function<void(const std::string &)> & handler)
            {
                read_handler_ = handler;
            }

            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            /// <summary>   Asynchronously writes the provided message to the connection. </summary>
            ///
            /// <remarks>   Falven, 3/1/2016. </remarks>
            ///
            /// <param name="message">  The message to write. </param>
            /// <param name="handler">  A handler to invoke when the message has been written. </param>
            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            void write_async(const std::string & message,
                const std::function<void(const std::string &)> & handler = {})
            {
                io_service_.post([this, message, handler]()
                {
                    bool empty = message_queue_.empty();
                    message_queue_.push(std::make_tuple(message, handler));
                    if (empty)
                    {
                        do_write();
                    }
                });
            }

        private:
            boost::asio::io_service & io_service_;
            boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver_;
            boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket_;
            std::queue<std::tuple<std::string, std::function<void(const std::string &)>>> message_queue_;
            boost::asio::streambuf reply_buffer_;
            std::function<void(const std::string &)> read_handler_;
            bool resolved_;
            bool connected_;

            void do_error(const std::string & message,
                const boost::system::error_code & error)
            {
                close();
                throw irc_exception(message, error);
            }

            void do_connect(boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator,
                const std::function<void(const boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator & iterator)> & handler = {})
            {
                boost::asio::async_connect(socket_,
                    endpoint_iterator,
                    [this, handler](const boost::system::error_code & error, boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator iterator)
                {
                    switch (error.value())
                    {
                        case boost::system::errc::success:
                        {
                            connected_ = true;

                            do_read();

                            if (!message_queue_.empty())
                            {
                                do_write();
                            }

                            if (handler)
                            {
                                handler(iterator);
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                        default:
                        {
                            do_error("Connect attempt failed", error);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

            void do_read()
            {
                boost::asio::async_read_until(socket_,
                    reply_buffer_,
                    message::TERMINATION,
                    [this](const boost::system::error_code & error, std::size_t)
                {
                    switch (error.value())
                    {
                        case boost::system::errc::success:
                        {
                            std::string read((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(&reply_buffer_)),
                                std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
                            if (read_handler_)
                            {
                                read_handler_(read);
                            }
                            do_read();
                            break;
                        }
// In case connection is lost.
#ifdef _WIN32
                        // 10009
                        case WSAEBADF:
                        // 10057
                        case WSAENOTCONN:
#else
                        case boost::system::errc::not_connected:
#endif
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        default:
                        {
                            do_error("Receive reply failed", error);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

            void do_write()
            {
                if (resolved_ && connected_)
                {
                    auto next_msg = std::get<0>(message_queue_.front());
                    boost::asio::async_write(socket_,
                        boost::asio::buffer(next_msg.c_str(), next_msg.size()),
                        [this](const boost::system::error_code & error, std::size_t)
                    {
                        switch (error.value())
                        {
                        case boost::system::errc::success:
                        {
                            auto next = message_queue_.front();
                            message_queue_.pop();

                            auto next_callback = std::get<1>(next);
                            if (next_callback)
                            {
                                next_callback(std::get<0>(next));
                            }

                            if (!message_queue_.empty())
                            {
                                do_write();
                            }
                            break;
                        }
// In case connection is lost.
#ifdef _WIN32
                        // 10009
                        case WSAEBADF:
                        // 10057
                        case WSAENOTCONN:
#else
                        case boost::system::errc::not_connected:
#endif
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        default:
                        {
                            do_error("Send request failed", error);
                        }
                    }
                });
                }
            }
        };
    }
}

#endif
```

The pre-processor directives in the error switch address a cross-platform bug with boost.

The following illustrates a "Raw" case usage of the connection class.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
#include <thread>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

#include "dapps/irc/connection.hpp"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    try
    {
        boost::asio::io_service io_service;
        // Prevent the io service's run loop from ending before async calls.
        boost::asio::io_service::work work(io_service);
        // Run io service even processing loop on another thread.
        std::thread io_thread([&io_service]() { io_service.run(); });

        dapps::irc::connection con(io_service);

        con.establish_async("irc.deltaanime.net", "6667",
            [](const boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator & iterator)
        {
            std::cout << "Connected to: " << iterator->host_name() << std::endl;
        });

        con.read_async([](const std::string & read)
        {
            std::cout << "Received: " << read << std::endl;
        });

        auto sent_callback = [](const std::string & message)
        {
            std::cout << "Sent: " << message << std::endl;
        };
        con.write_async("PASS \r\n", sent_callback);
        con.write_async("NICK dapps\r\n", sent_callback);
        con.write_async("USER dapps 8 * :dapps\r\n", sent_callback);

        std::cin >> std::string();

        con.close();
        io_thread.join();
    }
    catch (std::exception & e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is the end goal to use `read_async` and `write_async` directly, or would this be wrapped into a higher level interface of some kind? The only thing that jumps out at me is that this is still very, very low level to be considered somehow tied to the IRC protocol, but I suspect that's intentional based on your opening sentence. I'm just not sure if you mean this would be used to make a higher level API or if you mean that this would be used directly to make bots/clients/etc.

Comment: @Corbin, this is low level. I am also working on a twitch_client and client classes that use this object via composition to connect and exchange messages with a server - i intentionally designed it this way because different irc servers adhere to the irc protocol differently. For example, the irc rfc requires sending a pass message followed by nickname followed by user, however, some other servers (twitch irc) may do it in a different order.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. I didn't know various IRC servers strayed from the spec a significant amount. That's unfortunate :/.